# What arguments does Plato's Lysis put forth from 216 to 223?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, plato

I don't understand this part. He seems to go back and forth on whether they support one another and whether they are actually successful. Some serious clarification is needed.

Comment: See Terry Penner & Christopher Rowe, Plato's Lysis (Cambridge University Pressy, 2005), **Ch.5** 216c1–221d6: what it is that loves, what it really loves, and why

Comment: And see also [Wiki's Lysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysis_(dialogue)#The_presence_of_bad_is_the_cause_of_love_(philia)_[216c%E2%80%93218c]): "it is a dialogue of Plato which discusses the nature of *philia* (φιλία), often translated as friendship. [...] The Greek word which in the context of its time was more than just "friendship", and referred to an intimate love that developed between free men, a love that in certain cases could include the erotic. [...[ The search continues in an attempt to determine the first principle of friendship. "

Comment: The dialogue (an early one) shows the typical Socrates' approach to *investigation*: the search for a *definition*. As often (always?) it ends in a disappointing way: "Socrates ends by admitting that for all their discussion, a proper definition is still elusive. And yet, Socrates says that he considers the two boys, Lysis and Menexenus, as friends, even though he failed to define it properly.  1/2

Comment: Although Socrates managed to refute all of his definitions, there are reasons to believe that his last, the one where loving friendship exists between one who is good and one who is in-between, is what Plato intended as true, a definition consistent with the one Socrates gives of eros in the Symposium." 2/2